# AWS Terraform error: "expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: with err: invalid CIDR address:"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Practicing with AWS security groups in Terraform. I'm moderately experienced with TF but SGs have been tricky. I have the following main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "test" {
cidr_block = var.cidr_block
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
name = var.name
vpc_id = aws_vpc.test.id
description = var.description
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rule" {
type = "ingress"
from_port = var.from_port
to_port = var.to_port
protocol = var.protocol
cidr_blocks = var.cidr_blocks
security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg.id
}
```

I have variables for the above in a variables.tf file (can show on request), and my modules are below:

```
provider "aws" {
region = "us-east-1"
}

module "vpc" {
source = "../"
cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

module "TestSG1" {
source = "../"
name = "Test"
description = "Test"
type = "ingress"
from_port = 0
to_port = 65535
protocol = "tcp"
cidr_blocks = ["192.168.0.0/16"]
}
```

When run Terraform Plan on the above configuration, I get this error:

> Error: expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: with err:
> invalid CIDR address:
>
> on ..\vpc.tf line 6, in resource "aws_vpc" "test":
>
> 6: cidr_block = var.cidr_block

Now, if I REMOVE the cidr_block line from the vpc module and instead hardcode that same cidr_block value into main.tf, like so:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "test" {
cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

....then I can apply the code no problem, the two modules deploy successfully. So something only goes wrong when I insert the cidr_block line into the VPC module. If I run the VPC module in isolation - apart from the SG resources and module - it runs fine with the cidr_block variable in the module aws well. Something is wrong in the interplay between the two. Exhausted my research so turning to the Stackoverflow brain trust. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Sharing my variables too, for good measure.

```
variable "cidr_block" {
description = ""
type = string
default = ""
}

variable "name" {
description = ""
type = string
default = ""
}

variable "description" {
description = ""
type = string
default = ""
}

variable "type" {
description = ""
type = string
default = ""
}

variable "from_port" {
description = ""
type = number
default = 0
}

variable "to_port" {
description = ""
type = number
default = 0
}

variable "protocol" {
description = ""
type = string
default = ""
}

variable "cidr_blocks" {
description = ""
type = list(string)
default = []
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `cidr_block` variable is empty. Do you want to read the value from your `variables.tf` file, or load it from the module?

Comment: I want to read it from the module, so I have the default value for the variable set to "".

Comment: You can [define an output value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) in your module and then access its value like [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/syntax.html#accessing-module-output-values), for instance `module.vpc.cdir_block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you are invoking the same module (code) twice with different parameters:

- once as `module vpc`
- and one more time as `module TestSG1`

As you have `default = ""` set for more most of the vars it's taking the default value for `cidr_block` you have in variables.tf while invoking the module as `TestSG1`, and as it's empty you are seeing:

`Error: expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: with err: invalid CIDR address:=`.

In order to fix it, you either need to invoke the module only once by passing all the required parameters properly or separating the VPC creation from the security group creation in a separate module.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Using outputs like another commented mentioned, I was able to get the modules to deploy successfully - but I multiple security groups and VPCs would be stood up, and I realized that the TestSG1 module is calling VPC code and standing up additional VPCs. Not the end of the world, but messy and I'm sure it could cause problems. I think I understand now why SGs are not often included in VPC repos, and are called separately. Thanks!